# How to disable double click zoom effect in standard map activity and add it for marker?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I found that the default event interface for markers are click and long click. So how to add custom *double click event listener* for marker?

But for that initially the double-click zoom feature for the map needs to be *disabled*. Not the whole zoom feature itself. I need to disable only the zoom that's invoked on double-click.How to code that?

Answer (score 3):

To disable  zoom feature ;

`map:uiZoomGestures="false"` inside your map xml tag

or

[`UiSettings.setZoomGesturesEnabled(false)`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings#setZoomGesturesEnabled%28boolean%29)

Read here too,

> Currently you are launching your activity on single click of marker
>   using the `onMarkerClick` api. In it why dont you use a timer
>   mechanism, which will record the number of clicks. You can do it in
>   following steps
>
> 1. Record time on click & id of marker.
> 2. Whenever you get click event on marker. Check if ID is same as previous one and also the time between both events is less than some
>      threshold.
> 3. If yes, Launch your activity.
> 4. If No, clear the saved id to new one and record time as well.

[how can handle double click on marker in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675071/how-can-handle-double-click-on-marker-in-android-application)

Comment: @Nobody yes if you are stuck you can always leave a comment ;)

Comment: your code disables **zoom** completely. I only wanted to remove the double click zoom feature

Comment: I wrote the code for that time diff, but that double click zoom on map is overriding this one